# flutter async to sync programming

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, flutter, dart

It's probably just me but asynchronous programming in flutter seems to be an absolute nightmare. Something really simple in javascript/typescript just seems to become unnecessarily hard. for example, I'm trying to make a simple function that checks if a user is authenticated:

```
Future<bool> isLoggedIn() async {
  var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  return user == null ? false : true;
}
```

and then use this function in a scenario like this:

```
Widget _buildChild() async {
    var auth = await user.isLoggedIn();
    if (auth) {
      return new Navigation();
    } else {
      return new LoginUI();
    }
}
```

But then the second function also needs to return a future?

*Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'.*

using then() instead of await doesn't work either. I've run into this issue several times before when using asynchronous programming in a synchronous context. maybe it's just the that it looks and feels very similar to Promises that I'm totally missing it's functionality from the docs.

Comment: I feel your pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change your code this way:

```
Widget _buildChild() {
  return FutureBuilder(builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData)
      return snapshot.data ? Navigation() : LoginUI();
    else
      return Container();
  },
  future: user.isLoggedIn(),);
}
```

It returns widget synchronously. If there is no data yet - it returns empty `Container`, and when `isLoggedIn()` returns value - this method will return needed widget

Comment: it works! awesome quick response. but how does this work, or is there any good documentation out there that explains futurebuilders in more detail?

Comment: look at this explanation: https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9

Comment: For handling some async operations I'd recommend to look `FutureBuilder` and `StreamBuilder` on the official site https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/widgets-library.html